# Convert htaccess rewrite rule to web.config

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis

I have been trying to convert a `.htaccess` rule to `web.config` but without luck, I tried the online tools to do that and tried some similar rules but I'm stuck with nothing, here's what I got:

```
// .htaccess
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?oldURL$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?e:/folder1/folder2/folder3(/.*)?$ http://newURL$1 [L,NE,R=301,NC]
```

I tried this rule in `web.config`:

```
<rule name="Redirect files" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^/?e:/folder1/folder2/folder3(/.*)?$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:www\.)?oldURL$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://newURL{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing in here ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why web.config can't rewrite the URL, but a redirection worked for me, I changed the action line:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="http://newURL{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

And I removed the condition :

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:www\.)?oldURL$" />
</conditions>
```

Now all my files are serverd with the new URL.